# Prove an equation is a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

> Show that $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} - λ * y(x) = 0$ is a Sturm-Liouville problem, where λ is a constant and x is periodic with period 2π

I'm just struggling with how to put this into Sturm-Liouville form.

I know the

> "x is periodic with period 2π"

is relating to $f(x) = f(x + 2π)$. But given that there is no value to $\frac{d y}{dx}$, there is no b(x), so B(x) is a constant, which kinda threw me off from an answer.

The notes I'm following have this on S-L:

> Consider the general form $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + b(x) \frac{d y}{dx} + c(x)y = λd(x)y $. Let B denote an antiderivative of b. This can be turned into Sturm-Liouville form, with conventional notation (with our choice of the sign of λ) (p(x)y ′)′ + q(x)y − λw (x)y = 0,
> where p(x) = e^B(x), q(x) = p(x)c(x) and w (x) = p(x)d(x).

Comment: I don't know if this is standard, could you put your definition of Sturm-Liouville from in the question?

Comment: What's wrong with writing your equation as $$(y')' = \lambda y,$$where then $p=1=w$, $q=0$? Isn't this enough to show that it's a Sturm-Liouville problem with your definition?

Comment: I don’t see the issue with $B$ being a constant. In this case $p$ is also a constant and is a common factor in the equation in your notes so you can cancel it out to obtain the same equation @Jose27 got